# Unwanted double quotes around members of Array in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote this code to make an Array containing my images:

```
listOfImages=(`find . -iname "*.png" 2>/dev/null`)
```

But the path could have spaces in it so I have to enclose every element in double quotes:

```
listOfImages=(`find . -iname "*.png" 2>/dev/null | sed -E -e 's/(.*)/"\1"/'`)
```

Normally when we print an Array's elements, it should not print the double quotes, example:

```
x=("a" "b")
for i in ${x[@]}
do
echo "$i"
done
```

And it prints:

```
a
b
```

But on my images Array, it prints with the double quotes which causes problems on the following codes on my script.

Demonstration:

```
for i in ${listOfImages[@]}
do
echo $i
done
```

And it prints:

```
"blocks/glass.png"
"blocks/glass_black.png"
```

Comment: `mapfile -t -d '' listOfImages < <(find  . -iname '*.png' -type f print0)`, also quote your variables, `"${listOfImages[@]}"` not `${listOfImages[@]}`

Comment: You'll also need to quote the array uses (`for i in "${x[@]}"`)

Comment: @Shayan : But you have put the double quotes there yourself, when you did the `"\1"` in your `sed` command1

Comment: @user1934428 I also put double quotes on this line: `x=("a" "b")` but they didn't get printed, see?

Comment: This is completely different. Your sed command has been enclosed in single quotes, but here you haven't. If you had written `x=('"a"' "b")`, you would have seen the double quotes around `a`, but not `b`.

Comment: @user1934428 Read the `sed` documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes in the output of your sed command have no syntactical meaning, i.e. they don't delimit the start and end of filenames. They're just *literal quotes* in the strings that go into your array. They **don't** protect you in any way from a filename like `my image.png` becoming two elements in your array.

Before making things more complicated, I'm wondering if you can use `globstar` to do a recursive expansion and get all your files ending with `.png`:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursive expansion of **
listOfImages=( **/*.png )
```

You almost always should loop through an array like:

```
for img in "${listOfImages[@]}" # quotes around the expansion
```

These quotes have syntactic meaning and prevent word-splitting from happening to the elements in your array, so `my image.png` is treated as a single element in the list.